# Copy() node in SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have made a copy from a node with `copy()` in Swift

For example:

```
var copy = original.copy() as! SKSpriteNode)
```

and this works fine.

My question is when I want to remove the original node (with removeFromParent) I also want to automatically remove the copy node.

How do I do that? I made a 2D spaceshooter (like Defender) and I used the copy node in the Radarcam.

Thanks.

Comment: Yo will have to keep track of the copy somewhere and remove it explicitly

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do I keep track of the copy? I have a function where I create 'enemy' nodes and at the same time copy of the nodes. So it is possible that there are more than one original en copy nodes. If I remove the copy node explicit in the contactdelegate then it removes the first copy node (and not the corresponding copy node of the original node).

Comment: You could use a dictionary `[SKNode:SKNode]` use the original as the key and the copy as the value. Then you can easily find the copy

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try it!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a class like this to keep track of the links between nodes (as suggested by *Paulw11*).

```
final class LinkedNodes {

    static let shared = LinkedNodes()
    private var links: [(SKNode, SKNode)] = []

    private init() { }

    func link(nodeA: SKNode, to nodeB: SKNode) {
        let pair = (nodeA, nodeB)
        links.append(pair)
    }

    func removeNodesLinked(to node: SKNode) {
        let linkedNodes = links.reduce(Set<SKNode>()) { (res, pair) -> Set<SKNode> in
            var res = res
            if pair.0 == node {
                res.insert(pair.1)
            }
            if pair.1 == node {
                res.insert(pair.0)
            }
            return res
        }
        linkedNodes.forEach { $0.removeFromParent() }
        links = links.filter { $0.0 != node && $0.1 != node }
    }
}
```

### Copying a node

Now just remember to create a link when you copy a node

```
let copy = original.copy() as! SKSpriteNode)
LinkedNodes.shared.link(nodeA: original, to: copy)
```

### Removing a node

Now you can remove all the linked nodes of a given node writing

```
LinkedNodes.shared.removeNodesLinked(to: original)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and code example! I try it and let you know if it works for me!

Comment: I gives this error: Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(((SKNode, SKNode)) throws -> Bool)'

Comment: @JohanKornet Fixed!

Comment: @JohanKornet `res` is a parameter, it's immutable so I cannot change it. But I need to mutate it in order to call `.insert`. So I create a mutable copy of `res` and then I am able to mutating it.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution, make a node to parent both the original and copy, and then just remove the parent when not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but the original is added to another parent then the copy. Could you give an example of the code?

Comment: .... you take the original parent of the child and make it the child of the parent, so instead of scenenode -> spritenode it is scenenode->spritecontainernode->spritenode. Then removing the container removes the sprite. If I post the code then you won't learn the concept of how it works, so you won't apply the idea to other problems in the future.